# Need help with an analytic solution of an integral of a particle within an infinite potential well

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, quantum-mechanics

While working on a homework problem related to an infinite potential well, I encountered the following integral:
$$ \int_0^L \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right) \sqrt{x(L-x)}\mathrm{d}x $$

This integral is crucial for determining the expansion coefficients of my wavefunction. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to find an analytical solution. Any guidance or assistance in solving this integral would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Pretty important detail I missed is that $n$ is an integer greater than zero.

Comment: You will need Bessel functions according to software

Comment: If $n$ is even, the integral is zero by symmetry. A c.a.s. gives that if $n = 2 m + 1$ is odd, then the integral has value $$(-1)^m \frac{L^2}{2 n} J_1\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right) ,$$ where $J_\alpha(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function